# Get files by filename mask

Tags: c#, regex, getfiles

fileNameMaskI need load files from directory by filename mask, if filename begin with "Table 1" work well, but if directory contain any files: "TestTable 1 someValue.xlsx" or "Test Table 1 someValue.xlsx" my mask not work.

If I change mask to "^(Table 1).*\.xlsx$" - Directory.GetFiles return all files with "Table 1", but I need return only files where file name start from "Table 1".

```
My test code:

 var fileNameMask = "(Table 1).*\\.xlsx";
 string path = @"c:\Temp\";
 Regex searchPattern = new Regex(fileNameMask);
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Whats wrong with a simple: `Path.GetFileName(f).StartsWith("Table 1")`?

Comment: I need used regex because loading a various files with different mask. I have template for this files with file name mask

Comment: I'm bad at Regex, why not  Table 1^.*\.xlsx$ or  Table 1(^).*\.xlsx$ don't it start with Table 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mask:

```cs
string maskfile = @"[^\w\s](Table 1)(.*)(.xlsx)";
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to use built-in functionality of GetFiles method?

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "Test 1*.xlsx")
```

Comment: I must used regex search pattern

Comment: Why only regex? Masks are much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
private String[] GetFilesByMask(string pPath)
{
    Regex mask = new Regex(sFileMask.Replace(".", "[.]").Replace("*", ".*").Replace(".", "."));
    Return Directory.GetFiles(pPath).Where(f => mask.IsMatch(f)).ToArray();

}
```